# NixOS: setting package configuration globally (for all packages)

Tags: nixos

On NixOS, I'm trying to compile my system without Gnome.
For example, network-manager/openconnect has a withGnome option:

```
{ stdenv, fetchurl, openconnect, intltool, pkgconfig, networkmanager, libsecret
, withGnome ? true, gnome3, procps, kmod }:
```

I would like to set that to false; but while I could do that with an overlay,
I'm unclear how to set withGnome to false for *all* packages built as part of the system.

In 6.1.1 of the nixos manual, is the following; but this seems to be about overriding a single package for the benefit of all dependents, rather than overriding all packages with a single option.

> The overrides shown above are not global. They do not affect the
>   original package; other packages in Nixpkgs continue to depend on the
>   original rather than the customised package. This means that if
>   another package in your system depends on the original package, you
>   end up with two instances of the package. If you want to have
>   everything depend on your customised instance, you can apply a global
>   override as follows:

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In Nixpkgs, package options have no shared meaning across packages, so it might be hard to get rid of all dependencies to Gnome. There is a chance that you'd need to write quite a lot of overrides for it. `nix why-depends` can help a lot here.

Nethertheless there is a *module* option called [`environment.noXlibs`](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#noxlibs), which turns off every usage of a `withGnome` package option I could find in Nixpkgs. So maybe there is an easy way?